How to make the key slot to unlock at GRUB stage to be the first active one?
I am following the Debian dev's guide to full disk encryption to secure an Ubuntu machine and I am confused at section 3. It states:

Note: cryptomount lacks an option to specify the key slot index to open. All active key slots are tried sequentially until a match is found. Running the PBKDF algorithm is a slow operation, so to speed up things you’ll want the key slot to unlock at GRUB stage to be the first active one. Run the following command to discover its index.

root@debian:~# cryptsetup luksOpen --test-passphrase --verbose /dev/sda5
Enter passphrase for /dev/sda5:
Key slot 0 unlocked.
Command successful.

And that's the end of the section. It seems like we're not done yet? Ok, so we've found the index (in my case it's 1, not 0), now what? How do we "[set] the key slot to unlock at GRUB stage to be the first active one", as the guide says? Seems like the guide cuts off early.
Thank you!

You quoted the end of the guide's Section #3.  Have you seen the commands and descriptions in the guide's Section 4, Step 3?  They seem to answer your question about how to specify the key slot index in the /etc/crypttab file.  (but I've only skimmed the guide, perhaps I've misunderstood it)

OK, so now you know the passphrase you used is in key slot #1 rather than key slot #0.
The next step is to find out whether key slot #0 is in use or not. You can list the state of each key slot with a cryptsetup luksDump <encrypted disk device>.
If the key slot #0 is listed as DISABLED, it is currently free, and you can simply assign the passphrase you'll want to use with GRUB to it:
cryptsetup luksAddKey --new-key-slot 0 --verify-passphrase <encrypted disk device> 

But if the key slot #0 is listed as ENABLED, it is already in use. In that case, you must find out what it's used for, and add that passphrase or key file to another slot if you want to keep that functionality.

This refers to the number in order.
Since the slots count starts from 0,
slot with the number 0 is the "first" one,
slot 1 is the "second", slot 2 is the "third" and so on
